# why i'm getting plugin has no name in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i Have created this plugin but when i try to upload it on wordpress repository it retrieve this error:
Error: The plugin has no name. Add a Plugin Name: line to your main plugin file and upload the plugin again. For more information, please review our documentation on Plugin Headers.

but the plugin name it's there in the first line, i can't understand why i'm reciveing this error.

here the main plugin file:

```
      <?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       Wp Sitemap Disable
 * Plugin URI:        https://github.com/ale0211/wp-disable-sitemap
 * Description:       Lightweight Disable Sitemap
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * Requires at least: 5.2
 * Requires PHP:      7.2
 * Author:            Alessandro Amato
 * License:           GPL v2 or later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Update URI:        https://github.com/ale0211/wp-disable-sitemap
 * Text Domain:        Wp-Sitemap-Disable
 * Domain Path:       /languages
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'Not allowed' );

function sitemap_off() {
         remove_action( 'init', 'wp_sitemaps_get_server' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'sitemap_off');
```

Comment: Maybe try without all the stars - and just enclose it all in a single `/**/`

Comment: I've tried but its the same error